# Deployment of SpringMvcGroovy-0.1.0.jar to CloudFoundry fails

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-boot

When I try to deploy [SpringMvcGroovy-0.1.0.jar](https://github.com/philwebb/SpringMvcGroovy) to CloudFoundry with '***cf push SpringMvcGroovy -p libs/SpringMvcGroovy-0.1.0.jar***' command, it uploads droplet successfully but fails to start the instance:

```
...
2014-06-11T03:04:43.37-0400 [App/0] OUT 2014-06-11 07:04:43.373 INFO 33 --- [ main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port: 8080
2014-06-11T03:04:43.37-0400 [App/0] OUT 2014-06-11 07:04:43.376 INFO 33 --- [ main] c.b.springmvc.GreetingApplication : Started GreetingApplication in 5.263 seconds (JVM running for 6.868)
2014-06-11T03:05:36.53-0400 [DEA] OUT Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2014-06-11T03:05:36.54-0400 [API] OUT App instance exited with guid 83d01863-9813-4b7b-8113-a2a8fcc8a43d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"83d01863-9813-4b7b-8113-a2a8fcc8a43d", "version"=>"9baf1eef-275f-4000-bcde-f0810985e9a6", "instance"=>"31ec2e2f0a704d2cb7555bfbbcb26aa0", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1402470336}
2014-06-11T03:05:36.65-0400 [App/0] ERR
```

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app seems to be starting on port 8080 (which obviously isn't going to work). The buildpack ought to detect a Spring Boot app and set the `server.port` argument, so something is broken there (raise an issue with them if you want to get it fixed: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues?state=open). You can work around it be setting `SERVER_PORT=${PORT}` yourself as an environment variable.

EDIT: I wouldn't bother raising any issues. The app works for me if I upgrade to Spring Boot 1.1.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.0.2.RELEASE did it for me. Thank you for quick response, Dave.
PS: I don't see 1.1.0.RELEASE version of spring-boot-starter-web here:
http://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
only RC and milestones. The same goes for spring-boot-gradle-plugin.

Comment: 1.1.1.RELEASE is also out now in maven central. The indexers don't always reflect what's in the repo right away (takes days sometimes apparently).